# Keyerror when trying to modify column values based on column from another datafrme

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

I have two pandas dataframes (df1 and df2).

df1

```
address     mon    tue    wed    ...
address1     40     40     40    ...
address2     20     20     20    ...
address3     30     30      0    ...
address3      0      0     30    ...
...         ...    ...    ...    ...
```

df2

```
address     mon    tue    wed    ...
address1      0     15      0    ...
address2      0      6      0    ...
address3     15      0      0    ...
...         ...    ...    ...    ...
```

What I want to do is when the value in a column of df1 (eg. mon) is greather than 0, if the value in df2 is also greather than 0 then replace the value of df1 by the value of df2:

df1 modified

```
address     mon    tue    wed    ...
address1     40     15     40    ...
address2     20      6     20    ...
address3     15     30      0    ...
address3      0      0     30    ...
...         ...    ...    ...    ...
```

I'm trying this code [based on this](https://python.tutorialink.com/pandas-modify-column-values-based-on-another-dataframe/):

```py
for index, _ in df1.iterrows():
    if df1.loc[index, 'mon'] > 0:
        df1.loc[index, 'mon'] = float(
            df2.loc[(df2['address'] == df1[index, 'address']), 'mon'])
```

But I get a `KeyError: (4, 'address')`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3361, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 76, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: (4, 'address')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/project/script.py", line 78, in <module>
    df2.loc[(df2['address'] == df1[index, 'address']), 'mon'])
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3458, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3363, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: (4, 'address')
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you meant `df1.loc[index, 'address']`. Multiple Indexers without loc is looking for MultiIndex column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mask` and `combine_first`.

Set `address` column as index of both dataframes then create a boolean mask where df1 and df2 values are greater than 0. Use `mask` to set each cell that match condition to NaN and use `combine_first` to fill NaN values of df1 by values of df2.

```
df1 = df1.set_index('address')
df2 = df2.set_index('address').reindex(df1.index)
mask = df1.gt(0) & df2.gt(0)
df1 = df1.mask(mask).combine_first(df2).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
    address   mon   tue  wed
0  address1  40.0  15.0   40
1  address2  20.0   6.0   20
2  address3  15.0  30.0    0
3  address3   0.0   0.0   30
```

Comment: It looks great, but when I run it I get a `ValueError: putmask: mask and data must be the same size` in the line `df1 = df1.mask(mask).combine_first(df2).reset_index()`. Both dataframes must have same number of rows?

Comment: No. I reused your 2 dataframe with 4 and 3 rows.You have to use mask on the longest dataframe. I reproduced your error. Maybe I could find a more robust solution if needed

Comment: In the real data df1 is longer than df2. I tryied using the mask in both dataframes but with the same message (also replacing 0 by NaN to adjust the dataframes to the pandas documentation of combine_first) but the message is still the same.

Comment: Is it possible to share an example that does not work, please?

Comment: Here is an example of df1 and df2 https://ufile.io/f/rycj2

Comment: I updated my answer. I reindexed `df2` by `df1` to have two dataframes with the same rows. I tested on your files and it worked.

Comment: Great, I just reaggregate back the combined dataframe to have just a row per address in some cases and it is perfect. Thanks a lot.